# How to show that the $L^2(\pi)$ convergence $ \| P_tf-\pi(f)\|_2 \to 0 $ for semigroups of Markov chains?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis

For Ornstein-Uhlenbeck (OU) process,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ouprocess}
    dX_t=-X_tdt+\sqrt{2}dB_t.
\end{equation}
define \begin{equation}
    E[f(X_t)|X_0=x]=P_tf(x),
\end{equation}
for all $f\in C_b(R^n)$.

We know that let $\pi$ be the standard Gaussian measure on $R^n$ (i.e., $\pi(x)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}e^{-\|x\|^2/2}$). The OU process admits $\pi$, where convergence holds in $L^2(\pi)$ for any bounded and smooth function $f:R^n\to R$:
$$
\| P_tf-\pi(f)\|_2\to 0
$$
where $\pi(f)=\int fd\pi$.

***Question:***

I try to get the stationary distribution $\pi$ for the following SDE:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:ld}
    dX_t=-\nabla H(X_t)dt+\sqrt{2}dB_t, \, X_0=x,
\end{equation}
where $H(t)$ is the potential function on $R^n$. When we take $H(X_t)=X_t\cdot X_t/2$, the above Langevin dynamics are same as the OU process.

How to show that the $L^2(\pi)$ convergence
$$
\| P_tf-\pi(f)\|_2 \to 0
$$
where $\pi(dx)=e^{-H(x)}dx/Z$ and $Z=\int e^{-H(x)}dx$ called Gibbs measure.